# Bootstrap 3 Select drop down mis-alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use an input text box along with a selection box of custom height and width, but I couldn't align them properly:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 600px; height: 30px" />
    <select class="form-control">
        //options here
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="<portlet:namespace/>productSearchBtn">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

and the output looks something like this
[image]

then I set a custom width for Select button [width: 300px],
[image]

It seems like the input text box, select drop down and submit button are misaligned.

Please...how can I fix them so both are aligned properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be looking at [Bootstrap 3.0 grid-column structure.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

[**Here's what you are looking for**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhFB8/)

**Markup:**

```
    <!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control">//options here</select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="<portlet:namespace/>productSearchBtn">Search</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the bootstrap grid system insteed of fixing width http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: sorry that didn't help. The result is most similar like 1st image with slight difference.

Comment: FYI, I just wrapped each element with div type col-md-*

Comment: Yes wrap each element in col-md-* div: the fist fo exemple col-md-4 the second col-md-4 and third col-md-2 => the sum is 12 columns

Answer (score 1):

Try with `form-inline` and `form-group`

```
<form class="form-inline">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Categories</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="<portlet:namespace/>productSearchBtn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my OP, I used form with 'form-inline' and role='form'

Answer (score 0):

All thing you should do is wrap the entire thing in `form-inline` class and `form-group`

**Code**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>All Categories</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="<portlet:namespace/>productSearchBtn">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my OP, I used form with 'form-inline' and role='form'

Comment: @Reddy Can you check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/x2bkX/embedded/result/) If this is not you are looking, Please put your code in an another fiddle.